# Pypy compilation error

Tags: pypy

I'm trying to compile pypy on RHEL 6.6 and get the following mess of errors. I know it's a lot but here is the relevant information. It seems to get through the translation phase and tries to compile the C code:

```
[translation:ERROR]     /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libexpat.a(xmlparse.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC                                                                                                                                                                                         
[translation:ERROR]     /usr/lib/libexpat.a: could not read symbols: Bad value                                                                                                       
[translation:ERROR]     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                                                                                                           
[translation:ERROR]     make: *** [libpypy-c.so] Error 1
```

So I guess this becomes a question of how do i do the  *recompile with -fPIC*? How do I pass the flag from the rpython call?

Comment: That's warnings only.  The error would be at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Looked for the error and found it.

Comment: I *think* the issue to be that libexpat.a is not a .so file, but a .a which cannot be used when building any .so (like libpypy-c.so).  You need to have libexpat.so first, I think.  I certainly see on my Ubuntu system that it has both /usr/lib/libexpat.a and /usr/lib/libexpat.so...  (The error message from gcc is confusing, because we are passing -fPIC.  I think what it means is that you should recompile *libexpat* with this flag, which is normally what you get in libexpat.so.)

Comment: Ok. thanks. i'm using my own copy of libexpat on a system i don't have root access to. I'm not sure why the libexpat.so didn't install but reinstalling now.